# customizing heatmap using data stored in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe `z1` with entries as follows:

```
z1.ix[1:10,1:3]
            2017-04-01  2017-05-01
2017-01-04         NaN    0.993549
2017-01-05         NaN         NaN
2017-01-06    0.830973    0.978463
2017-01-09    0.926456         NaN
2017-01-10    0.998371    0.997590
2017-01-11    0.997539    0.999364
2017-01-12    NaN         0.989801
2017-01-13    0.999701    0.998526
2017-01-16    0.995119    0.998891
```

Both index and column names are datetime objects.

I am trying to create heat map for the above dataframe so I am doing the following:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

s = StringIO("""
            2017-04-01  2017-05-01
2017-01-04         NaN    0.993549
2017-01-05         NaN         NaN
2017-01-06    0.830973    0.978463
2017-01-09    0.926456         NaN
2017-01-10    0.998371    0.997590
2017-01-11    0.997539    0.999364
2017-01-12    NaN         0.989801
2017-01-13    0.999701    0.998526
2017-01-16    0.995119    0.998891""")
z1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(s, sep='\s+')
sns.heatmap(z1, annot=True)
```

I have the following questions:

(1) By default it uses red and black scale, how do I use green and red scale?

(2) How do I control the display of x and y axes ticks. I want to tilt them at an angle as I have about 100 columns and hence I want to use only 10 ticks aligned at an angle.

(3) How do I control the display of y axis ticks? Right now I am not sure what it displays. I want it displayed in the format '%Y-%m-%d'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you need to use the "cmap" parameter.

For your second question, you need to use set_xticklabels() with the rotation parameter or the set_yticklabels() depending on what axis you want.

For your third question you need to do z1.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

s = StringIO("""
            2017-04-01  2017-05-01
2017-01-04         NaN    0.993549
2017-01-05         NaN         NaN
2017-01-06    0.830973    0.978463
2017-01-09    0.926456         NaN
2017-01-10    0.998371    0.997590
2017-01-11    0.997539    0.999364
2017-01-12    NaN         0.989801
2017-01-13    0.999701    0.998526
2017-01-16    0.995119    0.998891""")
z1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(s, sep='\s+')
# Change the date format of index column
z1.index =  z1.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
g = sns.heatmap(z1, annot=True,cmap="RdYlGn")
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30)
```

[image]

You could try other parameters for cmap based on the colors you want like:

Possible values are: Accent, Accent_r, Blues, Blues_r, BrBG, BrBG_r, BuGn, BuGn_r, BuPu, BuPu_r, CMRmap, CMRmap_r, Dark2, Dark2_r, GnBu, GnBu_r, Greens, Greens_r, Greys, Greys_r, OrRd, OrRd_r, Oranges, Oranges_r, PRGn, PRGn_r, Paired, Paired_r, Pastel1, Pastel1_r, Pastel2, Pastel2_r, PiYG, PiYG_r, PuBu, PuBuGn, PuBuGn_r, PuBu_r, PuOr, PuOr_r, PuRd, PuRd_r, Purples, Purples_r, RdBu, RdBu_r, RdGy, RdGy_r, RdPu, RdPu_r, RdYlBu, RdYlBu_r, RdYlGn, RdYlGn_r, Reds, Reds_r, Set1, Set1_r, Set2, Set2_r, Set3, Set3_r, Spectral, Spectral_r, Vega10, Vega10_r, Vega20, Vega20_r, Vega20b, Vega20b_r, Vega20c, Vega20c_r, Wistia, Wistia_r, YlGn, YlGnBu, YlGnBu_r, YlGn_r, YlOrBr, YlOrBr_r, YlOrRd, YlOrRd_r, afmhot, afmhot_r, autumn, autumn_r, binary, binary_r, bone, bone_r, brg, brg_r, bwr, bwr_r, cool, cool_r, coolwarm, coolwarm_r, copper, copper_r, cubehelix, cubehelix_r, flag, flag_r, gist_earth, gist_earth_r, gist_gray, gist_gray_r, gist_heat, gist_heat_r, gist_ncar, gist_ncar_r, gist_rainbow, gist_rainbow_r, gist_stern, gist_stern_r, gist_yarg, gist_yarg_r, gnuplot, gnuplot2, gnuplot2_r, gnuplot_r, gray, gray_r, hot, hot_r, hsv, hsv_r, icefire, icefire_r, inferno, inferno_r, jet, jet_r, magma, magma_r, mako, mako_r, nipy_spectral, nipy_spectral_r, ocean, ocean_r, pink, pink_r, plasma, plasma_r, prism, prism_r, rainbow, rainbow_r, rocket, rocket_r, seismic, seismic_r, spectral, spectral_r, spring, spring_r, summer, summer_r, tab10, tab10_r, tab20, tab20_r, tab20b, tab20b_r, tab20c, tab20c_r, terrain, terrain_r, viridis, viridis_r, vlag, vlag_r, winter, winter_r